# Importing gTTs into Python issue

Tags: python, google-text-to-speech

When I enter the code in the Python Shell
I get this error.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Raav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Raav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\Raav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 839, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Raav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 344, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "C:\Users\Raav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 344, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\Raav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 412, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "C:\Users\Raav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 853, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\Raav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 1117, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1051)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Raav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\Raav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Users\Raav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 398, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='translate.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1051)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Raav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\gtts\tts.py", line 189, in write_to_fp
    part_tk = self.token.calculate_token(part)
  File "C:\Users\Raav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\gtts_token\gtts_token.py", line 28, in calculate_token
    seed = self._get_token_key()
  File "C:\Users\Raav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\gtts_token\gtts_token.py", line 55, in _get_token_key
    response = requests.get("https://translate.google.com/")
  File "C:\Users\Raav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Raav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Raav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Raav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Raav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='translate.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1051)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    tts.write_to_fp(mp3_fp)
  File "C:\Users\Raav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\gtts\tts.py", line 194, in write_to_fp
    str(e))
gtts.tts.gTTSError: Connection error during token calculation: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='translate.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1051)')))
```

Because I have correctly installed gTTS I am pretty sure.
I used the example that was given at https://pypi.org/project/gTTS/

The code that I used was

```
From gtts import gTTs
TTS = gTTS(‘hello’)
TTS.save(‘hello’)
```

I did not create a separate program I just entered each line separately in the IDLE.

Comment: Can you please include the code that generates this error? Just showing the error is not very informative.

Comment: @TomJohnson this is the code [click this link](https://pypi.org/project/gTTS/)